# Specifying another domain for a cookie

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, setcookie

On the server side (say Host1.com), where the Cookie (say Cookie1) is created and Domain is explicitly specified to some other domain (say Host2.com), does it have any meaning at all ?

I mean by doing so, is there any possibility that this Cookie1 would get attached to any requests made to Host2 at all (considering it to be like a 3rd party cookie) ?

I understand that with the SameSite option, we can control the scenarios where this cookie can get attached/sent along to the server from UI...But I assume all those scenarios would always be related to Host1 and not Host2 (despite us specifying the domain explicitly to Host2.com)

Comment: No, you can not set cookies for different domains. The browser will discard them.

Comment: Ok..In my case, I am unable to share cookies between  http://myui.app.abc.something.myhost.net and http://myserver.app.abc.something.myhost.net

So, cookie is created by myserver and despite setting the domain to myui, I cannot read on myui.
So, I assume this use case is treated as cross-domain, despite the part .app.abc.something.myhost.net being the same

Comment: _"despite setting the domain to myui, I cannot read on myui"_ - because those are different host names. But you should be able to specify that the cookie is valid for `app.abc.something.myhost.net` - then it should be valid for "subdomains" of that as well.

Comment: Oh k...so you are suggesting that if we set the domain to "app.abc.something.myhost.net", then the cookie can be read even on myui ?

Comment: Yes, it should work exactly that way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes: _"[...] if a domain is specified, then subdomains are always included"_